# How to make ragdoll follow animated object?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I have a ragdoll setup and want it to stick to an animated object so that the object drags the ragdoll around. Just parenting it doesn't work. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: maybe show us a link or animation how it should look like? thx.

Comment: I positioned it correctly and it just needs to stick to the arm and the rest of the body has to be ragdoll.